# Migrating Parse.com passwords to Django

Tags: python, django, authentication, parse-platform, bcrypt

I am trying to migrate the data from Parse.com to our own servers. In order to do this, user passwords have to be migrated too.
Parse.com uses standard bcrypt password encryption and passwords appear in the following format ([How would I move passwords out of Parse to another server?](https://www.parse.com/questions/how-would-i-move-passwords-out-of-parse-to-another-server)):

```
$2a$10$UpoNYQ0YE/FRVrh3xt6QQeQ3HmTmskbW2Sfg5DX9fDQJnIHQd1LqG
```

How do I move this string to Django auth_user table so it will be accepted by Django

**EDIT:**
I've tried adding BCrypt password hashers to settings according to **shtuff.it** suggestion below:

```
PASSWORD_HASHERS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.BCryptSHA256PasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.BCryptPasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.PBKDF2PasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.PBKDF2SHA1PasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.SHA1PasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.MD5PasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.CryptPasswordHasher',
)
```

And tried adding *bcrypt* to the beginning of the string: `bcrypt$2a$10$UpoNYQ0YE/FRVrh3xt6QQeQ3HmTmskbW2Sfg5DX9fDQJnIHQd1LqG`
This gives me "invalid salt" message from bcrypt hasher. I also tried playing with the string and bringing it to the form `bcrypt$<iterations>$<salt>$hash` form or some other combinations, but could not make the "invalid salt" message go away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you should be able to add bcrypt to PASSWORD_HASHERS in settings.py:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/passwords/#using-bcrypt-with-django

Comment: My actual mistake is described in another answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23150797/279813

Answer (score 2):

This is very stupid by me.
I had to make sure that `bcrypt` in the initial string is followed by double $$:
`bcrypt$$2a$10$UpoNYQ0YE/FRVrh3xt6QQeQ3HmTmskbW2Sfg5DX9fDQJnIHQd1LqG`.
Marking **shtuff.it** answer, as it is an actually correct one.

Comment: hey urk, how did you migrate the user model data? I am trying to do the same thing (migrate from parse to django), and any pointers will be helpful!

Comment: Just wrote a simple python script scanning users from Parse and storing them into local database.