# Migrating User Password from Rails To Django (Bcrypt)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, django

I'm moving our site from Rails to Django and have migrated the user password hashes.

1. Installed bcrypt via pip install bcrypt
2. In base.py, I have set the base hash in PASSWORD_HASHERS to:

   'django.contrib.auth.hashers.BCryptPasswordHasher'
3. Set the Django site's DJANGO_SECRET_KEY to Rail's SECRET_KEY_BASE.
4. Restarted the server

However, I still get an error that the password is incorrect.  The issue may or may not be related to [Migrating Parse.com passwords to Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23142571/migrating-parse-com-passwords-to-django/23150797#23150797), but I don't believe so as our Rails app is not using a salt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by bcrypt$ to the start of all of the user password hashes. Hence it was a duplicate of the related question.

Comment: can you pls link the answer to this, I'm solving the same issue.